# What are “named or labeled tuples” in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, tuples, namedtuple

Reading the changes in [Typescript 4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements), I found the new feature:

> Labeled Tuple Elements

I thought elements could either be indexed by numbers (like in tuples and lists) or by keys (like in dicts). I don't expected they could be indexed both ways.

my questions is:

- Why/when should I use named tuples instead of normal tuples?

Comment: They *can't* be "indexed both ways", the name labels are *metadata*. The actual value at runtime is still *just an array*, TS only exists at compile time.

Answer (score 48):

This is purely for documentation purposes, it has no semantics. They are just a way of putting names in the type signature--they type check identically to tuples without names, and the runtime behavior is identical as well.

> While these have **no impact on type-checking,** the lack of labels on tuple positions can make them harder to use – harder to communicate our intent.

Emphasis added.

Use them whenever you want to document what the names of elements in a tuple are in the type signature of a function that uses them.

### Example

You might have a `Range` type, which is `[start, end]`:

```
type Range = [start: number, end: number];
```

Or your `Range` type might be `[start, length]`:

```
type Range = [start: number, length: number];
```

Or you could use unnamed tuples:

```
type Range = [number, number];
```

These three definitions have *identical semantics* as far as TypeScript is concerned. You can access the members through destructuring by array access (e.g. `arr[0]`), just like any other array--they are not special. You cannot access the elements by name... again, these are just ordinary JavaScript array objects.

Comment: They do have _some_ impact on type checking if you spread them, though. Using `[x?: number]` as the arguments of a function will make the first param optional, whereas using `[number | undefined]` will not.

Comment: @m93a, you have to use the right syntax. If you want an optional entry in an unlabeled tuple, you do `[number?]`.

Comment: How do I access the name of an element of such a tuple?

Comment: @sayandcode: You cannot access the name.